# Database Unnecessary log Table - Magento2

Tags: magento2, database, log

To keep the DB optimized and clean, do we need to set up a cron to truncate the following tables?

```
customer_log;
customer_visitor;
report_compared_product_index;
report_event;
report_event_types;
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily;
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly;
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly;
report_viewed_product_index;
product_alert_stock;
search_query;
catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1;
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly;
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly;
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily;
```

Do empty tables at any level in live get affected?